# CustomCell with SWIFT and PARSE using PFTableViewCell and PFTableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

This is driving me bonkers, 
I am trying to create an custom cell with a prototype cells within Parse API - I have been banging my head for a whole day.

I don't have any error, but it doesn't work - I think there is a problem with my classes and whats a UITableView and whats PFTableViewCell, can someone who knows PARSE have a look at this please.

```
class CustomCell: PFTableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var EventTitle: UILabel!
}

class TableViewController: PFQueryTableViewController {




    override init!(style: UITableViewStyle, className: String!) {
        super.init(style: style, className: className)
    }


    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.parseClassName = "Events_"
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
        self.paginationEnabled = true
    }



    override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery! {

        var query = PFQuery(className: self.parseClassName)
        if (objects.count == 0)
        {
            query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly
        }
        return query

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject!) -> PFTableViewCell {



        var cell: CustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomCell

        cell.EventTitle.text = object["Title"] as NSString
        return cell


    }
```

Any help would be brilliant, thanks

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? What result do you get with the code you posted?

Comment: I don't get any result at all, just a blank tableview.

Comment: Can anyone help me here, this is so hard to get right...

Comment: Are you using a storyboard? If so, did you change the class of your table view controller to TableViewController there? Also, did you change the class of the cell to CustomCell?